# How to send Image as Mavlink Message

Tags: python, mavlink, qgroundcontrol

Actually , I tried to send Image as MavLink Message to QGC by following below link, but here I'm directly sending acknowledgement Data_Transmission_Handshake

https://mavlink.io/en/services/image_transmission.html
[image]

My Code: Data_Tansmission_Handshake(sending image metadata) mavlink messsage

```
imageMetaData = mavlink2.MAVLink_data_transmission_handshake_message(
            type     =     mavlink2.MAVLINK_DATA_STREAM_IMG_JPEG,# Type of requested/acknowledged data. (type:uint8_t, values:MAVLINK_DATA_STREAM_TYPE),
            size     =     62882 ,#total data size (set on ACK only). [bytes] (type:uint32_t),
            width    =     1391,# (type:uint16_t),
            height   =     614,# (type:uint16_t),
            packets  =      1,#Number of packets being sent (set on ACK only). (type:uint16_t),
            payload  =     len(image_to_bytes_("image_path")),#Payload size per packet (normally 253 byte, see DATA field size in message ENCAPSULATED_DATA) (set on ACK only). [bytes] (type:uint8_t),
            jpg_quality =  100,) # JPEG quality. Values: [1-100]. [%] (type:uint8_t)
```

image_to_bytes function:

```
def image_to_bytes_(image_path, target_width=1391, target_height=614, target_payload_size=253):
try:
    # Open the image file
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        # Read the image using PIL
        image = Image.open(image_file)
        # Resize the image to the target dimensions
        resized_image = image.resize((target_width, target_height))
        # Convert the image to a numpy array of uint8_t
        image_array = np.array(resized_image, dtype=np.uint8)
        # Flatten the array to a 1D array
        flattened_array = image_array.flatten()
        # Take only the first target_payload_size elements
        truncated_array = flattened_array[:target_payload_size]
        # Pad the array with zeros if needed to reach target_payload_size
        padded_array = np.pad(truncated_array, (0, target_payload_size - len(truncated_array)), 'constant')
        # Convert the array to bytes
        bytes_data = bytes(padded_array)
        print("bytes_data  ",len(bytes_data))
        return bytes_data
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"Error: File '{image_path}' not found.")
    return None
```

Encapsulated Data(send image chunks) mavlink messsage

```
    imageData = mavlink2.MAVLink_encapsulated_data_message(
            seqnr=0,
            data=image_to_bytes_("image_path")
       )
    master.mav.send(imageData)
```

master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('udpout:127.0.0.1:14550', source_system=1, source_component=1, dialect="ardupilotmega")

At QGC end , QGC is able to read this mavlink message, but in console its showing below message:

```
Using QByteRef with an index pointing outside the valid range of a QByteArray. The corresponding behavior is deprecated, and will be changed in a future version of Qt.

ImageProtocolManagerLog: getImage: Known header QImage::loadFromData failed
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong whether I'm not sending data correctly  or some other thing. Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, you are misunderstanding the image transmission protocol. See [this](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#ENCAPSULATED_DATA) and [this](https://github.com/zhao0079/mavconn/blob/master/src/comm/px_imagestreamer.cc#L78).